# Execute .ps1 file (without compile it)

Tags: powershell

I would like to execute a PowerShell script without manually load it (by clicking on the .ps1 file like it's a .bat). How can i do it? And what's the difference between .ps1 and .psc1?

Comment: I'd recommend searching on here if you haven't already done so. This question had already been asked multiple times. *`".psc1"`* stand for, "Powershell Console Files". Basically xml configuration files that will tell powershell what snapins to load automatically.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala And the first question? How do i execute a .ps1 file?